# How to pass path with spaces and trailing backslash to MSBuild as property

Tags: properties, msbuild

When I try to pass some directory path into MSBuild script as follows:

```
MSBuild.exe myproj.proj /p:DirPath="C:\this\is\directory\"
```

And in .proj file I use it as

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <FilePath>$(DirPath)file.txt</FilePath>
<PropertyGroup>
```

Then MSBuild composes `FilePath` as `c:\this\is\directory"file.txt`. If I pass `DirPath` without quotes but with trailing slash (`/p:DirPath=c:\this\is\directory\`) or without trailing slash but with quotes (`/p:DirPath="c:\this\is\directory\"`) then everything works fine.

What can be done to allow passing directory path with trailing slash (it would be more convenient) and in quotes (since path can contain spaces)? Or is it a bug in MSBuild and I should use some workaround, like removing trailing backslash upon passing it into msbuild?

Comment: Did you try single quotes?

Comment: @leppie this property is passed by build script and continuous integration tool (FAKE build tool) so I don't have any option here.

Answer (score 11):

It is because of the way the property is being set on the command line. MSBuild is adding the " to the end of the value because of the last '\' and therefore " is appended to the end of the string path.

Add a extra \ when setting the value from the command line and the string will append the backslash for you as intended or not place the " on the end.

```
MSBuild.exe myproj.proj /p:DirPath="C:\this\is\directory\\"
```

The value is then : C:\this\is\directory\file.txt

Another soulution is you can put this function in your MSBuild project to replace the " :

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DirPath>$(DirPath.Replace('"',""))</DirPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: IMO first solution is not to convenient, it's strange to pass two backslashes when all other backslashes passed by one. And the second solution wouldn't work in this form hence Properties in MSBuild sort of immutable, i.e. you can't override property passed via /p:propname=propvalue, you have to define new property like `<_DirPath>$(DirPath.Replace('"', ""))</_DirPath>`. I've decided to trim trailing backslash and append it in the .proj file.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that this is not an msbuild error. It is doing exactly what you are telling it to do. Append a " to the end of this property value. That is because you are setting the value with trailing \ which tells Msbuild that the next character should be included. In this case it is a ".Normally you would not put any trailing backslash on a directory property value. I am not sure why you consider the solution strange since in this case it is how you correctly set a directory variable with a needed "\" appended to the value. Glad you were able to figure out your own solution. Thanks